# Calling PHP Function through JavaScript with Parameter

Tags: javascript

```
        mysqli_query($con, $sql)

        mysqli_close($con);
}
```

How to use AJAX with PHP

Comment: There a PLENTY of tutorials out there on how to use AJAX, google it.

Comment: You shouldn't just comment unhelpfully. He needs help and perhaps you can refer him a link or something. Better than saying Google it.

Comment: @Epodax He doesn't seek tutorials. He's just asking for help as he wrote just above that he got confused. This website is to help each other, not for getting enough reputation to face down.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good answer with a good example.
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Also you might want to learn more about basics before going further. Try to google [ajax](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=ajax), [php ajax mysql](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=php+ajax+mysql) and find some tutorials.